# Line up img and div css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to line up `<img>` with a div but it seems like there is some margin/padding in `<img>`.

Here is what i tried:

```css
.Box {
  display: inline-block;
}

.myDiv {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
}

img {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Box">
  <div class="myDiv">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Box">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2VLDkNjAUBU/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

I wish it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: At a glance, take a look at `vertical-align`

Comment: Seems like declaring `.Box img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}` is all you'll need. `img` is an *inline* element by default so you'll need to *vertically align* it accordingly.

Comment: You should add border=0 on your HTML déclaration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default vertical alignment of inline elements is baseline, so you want something like bottom instead, and also remove the height on your box div (unless you want it 100px tall, which your example image doesn't show):

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Example:

```css
.Box {
  display: inline-block;
}

.myDiv {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
}

img {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="Box">
  <div class="myDiv">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Box">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2VLDkNjAUBU/maxresdefault.jpg" />
</div>
```